# Cannot make directory '/var/run/screen': Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, unix, gnu-screen

Sometime, usually after a crash or sudden shutdown, [`screen`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/screen) refuses to start. Commands like

```
screen
screen -ls
screen -r
screen -d
```

result in the following output

> Cannot make directory '/var/run/screen': Permission denied

What's the issue here? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Found a solution that doesn't require regular sudo on restarts

From ['Eric Z Ma' @ systutorials](https://www.systutorials.com/qa/1639/screen-reporting-cannot-directory-screen-permission-denied):

> The directory `/var/run/screen/` is the socket directory for screen.
>
> Fortunately, screen reads a environment variable `SCREENDIR` to get an alternative socket directory.
>
> So to work around it, you can create a directory, such as `~/.screen`:
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/.screen && chmod 700 ~/.screen
> ```
>
> and export the `SCREENDIR` to point to that directory:
>
> ```
> export SCREENDIR=$HOME/.screen
> ```
>
> You can also put this line into you `~/.bashrc` so that it will also take effect afterwards.

Comment: On WSL-Ubuntu 20.04 I fixed this by creating file `/etc/profile.d/screen.sh` containing the line `export SCREENDIR=$HOME/.local/run/screen`. This should solve the issue for all users on that machine.

Comment: improving @blerontin answer,  my /etc/profile.d/screen.sh (created and edited by root) is:  

  
#!/bin/bash  
mkdir -p $HOME/.local/run/screen  
chmod 700 $HOME/.local/run/screen  
export SCREENDIR=$HOME/.local/run/screen

Answer (score 58):

This issue has been documented [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/screen/+bug/574773). In short,

> `/etc/rcS.d/S70screen-cleanup` is running via upstart much earlier than it expects to have run, and is failing to correctly clean up that directory.

It can be fixed with the following command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/screen-cleanup start
```

Comment: This works, but I have to run it on every startup, otherwise I'll get the error again and again.

Comment: Worked on my ubuntu running in windows 10

Comment: @Krease See the other answer to this. Worked for me on WSL Ubuntu 20 https://superuser.com/a/1556866/35931

Answer (score 7):

In my case the `screen-cleanup` service was masked, on Debian "buster" 10.4:

```
$ systemctl is-enabled screen-cleanup.service

masked
```

And

```
$ file /lib/systemd/system/screen-cleanup.service

/lib/systemd/system/screen-cleanup.service: symbolic link to /dev/null
```

Which causes the following:

```
$ systemctl enable screen-cleanup.service

Synchronizing state of screen-cleanup.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable screen-cleanup
Failed to enable unit: Unit file /lib/systemd/system/screen-cleanup.service is masked.
```

The following did the trick to create the run-directory on every boot. Remove the symlink to `/dev/null` manually (`systemctl unmask` didn't work):

```
rm /lib/systemd/system/screen-cleanup.service
```

Then enable the service:

```
systemctl enable screen-cleanup.service
```

And start it:

```
systemctl start screen-cleanup.service
```

Comment: This solution would be nicer, but it brings other problems for WSL machines, since they [might not have systemd](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1424714).

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this while running a Centos / RHEL 7 based distro, and it doesn't have anything named 'screen-cleanup' anywhere under /etc.

A workaround I found was to simply run `sudo screen` and then immediately exit from it.

After that I was able to run screen without any special privileges, so it appears to clean up /var/run approriately up when given the chance.

Comment: Also had to `sudo chmod 777 /run/screen` after the initial `sudo screen` and then works fine **without** `sudo` , i.e. third time lucky. Only did this because on the second try it told me `Directory '/run/screen' must have mode 777.`

Answer (score 4):

I can fix this problem by executing the following commands.

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/screen
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/screen
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. Every time you restart you have to redo this.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: In Debian Stretch and later, make sure that `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` has been started successfully:

```
$:> systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
● systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service - Create Volatile Files and Directories
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-06-21 19:54:06 CEST; 41min ago
   ...
```

If disabled (`Loaded: ... ;disabled; ...`) then you might want to enable it with `systemctl enable systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service`. If you want to use screen within a [docker container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)) then you either have to get [systemd running in your container image](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/09/13/running-systemd-in-a-non-privileged-container/) or you have to run `systemctl start systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` or `/etc/init.d/screen-cleanup start` ([as suggested by Huey](https://superuser.com/a/1195963/629550)) each time after logging into your container.

**Details:** Since Debian Stretch, the startup script `/etc/init.d/screen-cleanup` is not executed, because by default this service is masked (`/lib/systemd/system/screen-cleanup.service -> /dev/null`), so systemd ignores it.

Instead `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` creates `/run/screen` on boot, as configured in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/screen-cleanup.conf`: `d /run/screen 0775 root utmp`

Comment: It looks like you are (also) suggesting a procedure that the OP would need to perform (manually) after every reboot. Can you offer a permanent solution, that would need to be done only once? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott `systemctl enable systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` that @Jacob suggested persisted across reboots.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when the root (`/`) directory is not owned by root, which causes the `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` service to fail.

Run `cd / && ll` to see who the owner of the root directory is.

Assuming it isn't `root`, run `sudo chown root:root /` to fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `ll` command is and I don't seem to have it, but I ran `getfacl /` and it indeed informed me my user owned /, whoops! Thank you :)